# take data of onclick

Tags: javascript, html

HTML: `<p onclick="myFunc()">This is a text</p>`

Javascript:

```
<script>

function myFunc(){
 //code something to console.log the HTML content of the  tag 
 //in this case it will console.log "This is a text"
}
</script>
```

I figure it is possible in jquery easily, but it is kind of outdated recently so I want to do it in pure Javascript way. I would love to hear some answers from you guys.

Comment: jQuery is pure JavaScript. It is just JavaScript written by other people. `onclick` attributes are generally best avoided, we've had [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/addEventListener) for at least two decades now.

Comment: `onclick` is not the modern way to do this. jQuery itself is not outdated, some just prefer not to have the extra overhead

Answer (score -2):

This is what you want ?

```
<p onclick="myFunc(this)">This is a text</p>

function myFunc(e){
  console.log(e.innerHTML);
}
```

If you want a function without parameters, you can try this :

```
function myFunc(){
  console.log(window.event.target.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: what does the `this` do to the `myFunc` function?

Comment: "this" will pass the current element to myFunc. Here, the current element is the "p" tag.